# Does snowflake try to retain the order of data in insert (including multi insert) and merge operations?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Data arrives as text (see `TEMPLATE_1`), it is processed into a table with with semi structured columns (see `TEMPLATE_2`). Templates

As the main source of data does not have any DML other than insert, I try to  maintain a good natural clustering behavior.

I collect the text in a table (of `TEMPLATE_1`) and I have a stream on that table, from which I use to process the new entries and move them further the data pipeline:

I process the rows for that day and using a multi table insert, I put it in a stage table `STAGE_TABLE` (see `TEMPLATE_2`). The process is a couple of steps long. First, a regex cleanup, a regex replace, then a string split to get the final fields.

If data fail the processing and have null fields, they go into `FAILED_ENTRIES` (see `TEMPLATE_1`)

The last step of processing is a sort on EVENT_DATETIME::DATE, COL_TYPE, and COL_JSON:ID.

Finally I `MERGE` it in the main table making sure that the whole record does not match (excluding row_created_at of course):

Will the sorting of data make it into order it exists in partitions,
or do I have to sort during merge,
or is there no way to guarantee this order.

```
CREATE TEMPLATE_1(
    RAW_DATA VARCHAR(16777216)
);

CREATE TEMPLATE_2 (
    EVENT_DATETIME TIMESTAMP_LTZ(9), 
    SOURCE_ID VARCHAR(16777216),    
    COL_TYPE VARCHAR(16777216),  
    COL_JSON VARIANT,
    ROW_CREATED_AT TIMESTAMP_LTZ(9),
);
```

Comment: Does your merge perform updates/deletes, or are you only using merge instead of insert to make sure a matching row does not already exist?

Comment: It only inserts if it does not find an exact duplicate.